# Issue where I can't float a DIV next to another DIV

Tags: css, html

I am struggling with getting a div to sit next to another div, but I can't seem to figure it out.

[image: image of css issue where text does not float]

I have a picture `projectLarge`, and a div `sideLargePicArea`, (which needs to sit next to the image) but everything I have tried has not worked. I thought `display: inline;` or `float: left;` would do the trick, also placing a `float: left;` on the `projectLarge` div, but no change.

HTML:

```
 <section class="projectLarge">
        <img src="/images/common/1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
             <article class="sideLargePicArea">
                <span class="smaller noTop">SMALLER</span>
                "Et af de mest markante transformationsprojekter i Danmark i nyere tid".
                <span class="smaller">SMALLER</span>
                "Et af de mest markante transformationsprojekter i Danmark i nyere tid".
             </article> 
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
/* The page sits inside a #container div */

#container {
    display: block; 
    max-width: 1320px;
    padding-left: 3vw;
}

/* */

.projectLarge {
    max-width: 1035px;
    margin: 0 5% 5% -3vw;
    float: left;    
}

.sideLargePic {
    float: left;
}

.smaller {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 5% 0 2% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made this easy for me but you can do some customization. You can float the direct children inside of the `section` all to the left. Additionally, the `img` and the `article` must have room in the section to float, otherwise the `article` will drop below the `img`. This is why I set both to `width:40%;`. You may or may not choose to do this.

```css
.projectLarge > *{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:40%;
}
```

```html
 <section class="projectLarge">
   <img src="/images/common/1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
   <article class="sideLargePicArea">
     <span class="smaller noTop">SMALLER</span>
     "Et af de mest markante transformationsprojekter i Danmark i nyere tid".
     <span class="smaller">SMALLER</span>
     "Et af de mest markante transformationsprojekter i Danmark i nyere tid".
   </article> 
</section>
```

Comment: thanks very much indeed! So, do all floated DIVS need to have a width attached to them, in order so they can float correctly?

Comment: When an element is floated, it then takes the width of its content. Sometimes that width is too much, so I've forced it instead.

Answer (score 1):

The image is taking up 100% of the containers space (.projectLarge), pushing the .sideLargePicArea down below it. To get them to sit side by side, you'll need to give them each a width that will fit side by side. I'd say use a percentage so when the container size changes, they'll always sit side by side. The image and the text container (.sideLargePicArea) percentage should add up to 100% or less.

Also, use padding on the text container (.sideLargePicArea) so the margins don't push the containers around. On the same note, add box-sizing: border-box; to all the elements. If you're unfamiliar with box-sizing, have a look at this post, it'll save you so much grief when making responsive layouts https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.projectLarge img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding 100px;
}
.sideLargePicArea {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="projectLarge">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
  <article class="sideLargePicArea">
    <span class="smaller noTop">SMALLER</span>
    "Et af de mest markante transformationsprojekter i Danmark i nyere tid".
    <span class="smaller">SMALLER</span>
    "Et af de mest markante transformationsprojekter i Danmark i nyere tid".
  </article>
</section>
```